# Supply different arguments for scipy.minimize in each iteration

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to supply a different arguments for each iteration in `scipy.minimize`.

What I am trying to do is:

```
res = minimize(func, x0, method='BFGS', args=(a,b,c))
```

Here, `func` is some large function. Inside `func`, there is a routine that outputs a log file. I want to take a log file from each iteration of the minimization process and carry out some analysis. However, in order to save log files with different names, I need to supply an iteration number to `func`. Is there any clever way to do it?

Comment: An ugly way would be a global variable an increment it...

Answer (score 0):

Counting the calls to the function is easy since `minimize` accepts a callable:

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import minimize
>>> 
>>> def func(x, a):
...    return (x-a)**2
>>> class Func(object):
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.count = 0
...    def __call__(self, x, a):
...       self.count += 1
...       return func(x, a)
```

Then,

```
>>> f = Func()
>>> minimize(f, [1.], args=(2.,))
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 4
    nfev: 12
     fun: 5.551115123125783e-17
       x: array([ 1.99999999])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    hess: array([[ 0.5]])
     jac: array([ 0.])
>>> f.count
12
```

Notice that the number of function calls per iteration depends on the minimizer and its arguments (whether you supply a hessian or not etc).